# how to auto generate xml or yaml mappers from existing db in doctrine 2... but not using cli

Tags: xml, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, auto-generate, mappers

I am new to ORM world and integrating doctrine 2 with zf project. I have gone through the doctrine documentation and various articles and integrated it :).

I have an existing DB from which I got to generate my mappers and entities. I am willing to use XML/YAML mappers instead of default annotations.

All I see everywhere is CLI commands to generate the mappers and entities, by executing the below commands in the bin directory where the "***doctrine.php***(provided in doctrine official docs)" file exists.

**To generate Mappers:**

```
         *php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database xml  /path/to/mappers*
```

**To generate Entities/Model Classes:**

```
         *./doctrine orm:generate-entities /path/to/models/or/entities*
```

But I dont want to execute the commands and generate the mappers/entities. I am looking for a PHP script which does it for me(**by calling an action method in a controller Ex: www.doctrineproj.com/admin/mdoels/autogenerate/**).

Do we have any API class or any way to do this by php code, instead of executing the CLI script. 
may be by calling like

**To generate mappers: doctrine_core:: generateMappers(dbParams,mapperDriver)**

**To generate entities: doctrine_core::generateEntities(metaData)**

OR

is there any way to execute all CLI commands from the php script file using the system like calls?

I tried using exec() and system() by using the above cli commands. But it isn't working well :(.

Here  is the code which I used to generate the mappers from my action method

public function autogenerateAction(){

```
     $result = array();
    //change the current working DIR to bin
    $cliPath = "cd ". APPLICATION_PATH . "/bin";
    exec($cliPath,$result);

    //construct the CMD to generate the XML files from the DB tables
    $mapperDir = APPLICATION_PATH. "/models/entities/xml-mapper/";
    $mapperType = "xml";

    $generateMappersCmd = "php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database  " . $mapperType . ' '  . $mapperDir ;

    //execute the CMD
    $result = system($generateMappersCmd);
```

}

but the above code is not creating the mappers at the destined directory.

Please suggest me a best solution to auto generate the mappers and entities from the DB using automated php script.

Looking forward a best solution.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try next (in some method of controller):

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$options = array(
    'command' => 'doctrine:generate:entity',
    '--entity' => "SomeDemoBundle:YourEntityName",
    '--fields' => "name:string(255) price:float description:text",
    '--with-repository' => true,
    '--format' => 'xml',
);

$fp = tmpfile();
$out = new StreamOutput($fp);
$in = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput($options);
$in->setInteractive(false);
$application->run($in, $out);
```